# How to get filename when using PHPickerViewController for photo

Tags: swift, swift3

How to get filename when using PHPickerViewController for photo

this is my function code

```
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        for item in results {
            item.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {(image, error) in
                if let image = image as? UIImage{

   
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help, thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hope you van find file name by using this:

```
item.itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: "public.item") { (url, error) in
                if error != nil {
                   print("error \(error!)");
                } else {
                    if let url = url {
                        let filename = url.lastPathComponent;
                        print(filename)
                    }
                }
            }
```

You can use this to get file name from `UIImagePickerController`

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL {
        let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [imageURL], options: nil)
        let asset = result.firstObject
        print(asset?.value(forKey: "filename"))

    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your gratitude ,but I change  if error == nil to if error != nil  it work and give filename finally.

Comment: No problem you can use that also.

Comment: Sorry i have 1 question.if i using UIImagePickerController  how to get filename like PHPickerViewController.

Comment: @SittipongWiangwaeng please check the updated answer.

Comment: i was looking for something else but this answer solve my 2 problems. Thanks @FaysalAhmed

Answer (score 3):

The `NSItemProvider` from `PHPickerResult` has a `suggestedName` property that will give you the file name. So from your provided code:

```
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    for item in results {
        item.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {(image, error) in
            // This will give you the file name
            guard let fileName = item.itemProvider.suggestedName else { return }
            if let image = image as? UIImage{
   
            }
        }
    }
}
```