# How to get image URL from PHPickerViewController?

Tags: swift, image, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller, phpickerviewcontroller

I want to select multiple images. Currently I was using `UIImagePickerController`. However, this does not allow multi-image selection as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291270/select-multiple-images-uiimagepickercontroller-or-photos-app-share-ui). So I'm looking into implementing this using the `PHPickerViewController`. However, to progress I need the image URL, as these selected images will be later uploaded. In `UIImagePickerController` it was fairly straightforward to get the url.

**Example**

```swift
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {

            if let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as? URL {
                // some logic
            } else {
                // error handling logic
            }
        }
```

I can't find any ways to achieve this using the `PHPickerViewController`. The closest I found was this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65912860/how-to-get-filename-when-using-phpickerviewcontroller-for-photo). But using this results in an invalid url. Which while uploading suggests the given image is empty.

Current logic as it stands is:

```swift
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
            
            guard !results.isEmpty else {
                picker.dismiss(animated: true)
                return
            }

            for item in results {
                
                let itemProvider = item.itemProvider
                
                itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: "public.item") { (url, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                       // Error handling
                    } else {
                        if let url = url {
                            // Got the URL but its wrong
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: The URL is not wrong, it's just temporary. Read the documentation for `loadFileRepresentation`. It states: *"This method writes a copy of the file’s data to a temporary file, which the system deletes when the completion handler returns."*.

Comment: Is there another way to get the URL which is not temporary?

Comment: You are getting the URL. That is the correct way. You either need to be done using the URL by the time the completion handler ends or you need to copy the file from the URL you are given to your own temporary location and then use that new URL.

Comment: Ahh I think I'll have to go down the route of "my own temporary location". Thanks